# C++ - Having a "uninitialized local variable y used" warning in my attempt to make a simple calculator

Tags: c++, function

this is my first post. I am having a issue getting my CML calculator to run, I know there are better ways to make a calculator than the code I have, so please leave suggestions and such in the comments, as i am a beginner programmer and it is important to receive feedback.

functions practice.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char oper;
    cout << "Welcome to this test calculator" << endl;
    cout << "Please Enter a operator to use: " << endl;
    cin >> oper;

    cout << "Enter a x and y value " << endl;
    cin >> x, y;

    calculate(x, y, oper);

    return 0;
}
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int calculate(int x, int y, char oper) {


    switch (oper)
    {
    case '-':
        return x - y;
        break;
    case '+':
        return x + y;
        break;
    case '*':
        return x * y;
        break;
    case '/':
        return x / y;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sorta typo: `cin >> x, y;` -> `cin >> x >> y;`

Comment: Debugging questions should include the error message verbatim (copy-and-paste it as text). It is also [advisable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to explain why your code should not trigger that error. In this case, the error message would point out which variable is uninitialized, and your task would be to point out the line where it is initialized.

Comment: functions practice.cpp(22): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'y' used

Comment: `#include "functions.cpp"` is also a potential problem. You should include headers, usually the .h files, and compile and link the implementation files. `#include` copies the included file into the including file.  Where this gets nasty is an IDE like Visual Studio may see functions.cpp and do the usual thing, compile and link it. Now you have the functions.cpp that was included in practice.cpp and functions.cpp both defining the same functions and the linker hates that. It doesn't know which is the real `calculate` and will emit an error.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `practice.cpp`:

`cin >> x, y;` should be `cin >> x >> y;`

`cin >> x, y;` will read input only for `x`.

Here `,` works as an end of the `cin` part, and `y` will work like a separate part.

Understanding of [comma operator (,)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) in the code:

Comma operator will always give priority to the right most operator.

ex: `x = (y,z);`

In this line, value of `z` will be assigned to `x`.

Same way in the line `cin >> x, y;`, `y` execute nothing. And after that `cin >> x` will read input from the user.